# Gremlin get count in javascript AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, gremlin

I am trying to get the count of edges for my graph through an AWS lambda 
 but getting an error

```
g.V(...).inE(...).outV(...).count(...).then is not a function
```

My lambda code is:

```
const gremlin = require('gremlin');
const DriverRemoteConnection = gremlin.driver.DriverRemoteConnection;
const Graph = gremlin.structure.Graph;

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {    
    let dc = new DriverRemoteConnection('ws://<endpoint>:8182/gremlin');

    const graph = new Graph();
    const g = graph.traversal().withRemote(dc);

    g.V('19071640').inE('friend').count().then(num => console.log(num));
}
```

It works if I do

```
g.V('19071640').inE('friend').outV().then(friends => console.log(friends));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to [iterate your traversal](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/#result-iteration).

```
g.V('19071640').inE('friend').count().next().then(num => console.log(num));
```